# how to create Jquery autocomplete textbox with multiple words separated by comma or semicolon in asp.net MVC4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

i want to create Jquery autocomplete textbox with multiple words separated by comma or semicolon in asp.net MVC4 using jquery ajax.. i have check here [a link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/07/jquery-autocomplete-textbox-with.html) but this donot provide my answer.plz check my code this is home controller function

//load tasks on autocomplete

```
    public JsonResult AutoCompleteTasks(string term)
    {
        var result = (from t in context.Tasks
                      where t.Name.Contains(term)
                      select new { t.Name }).Distinct();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

and my ajax function is

```
function multipleSearch(){
          $("#textarea").autocomplete({
              source: function (request, response) {
                  debugger;
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      url: "/Home/AutoCompleteTasks",
                      data: "{'term':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function(data) {
                          response(data.d);
                      },
                      error: function(result) {
                          alert("Error");
                      }
                  })
              },
          });

       }
```

here error in
 data: "{'term':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}", line...plz guide me

Comment: show `extractLast()` function definition